# Understanding `andThen`

Tags: scala, function-composition

I encountered `andThen`, but did not properly understand it.

To look at it further, I read the [Function1.andThen](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#andThen[A](g:R=%3EA):T1=%3EA) docs

```
def andThen[A](g: (R) ⇒ A): (T1) ⇒ A
```

`mm` is a [MultiMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html) instance.

```
scala> mm
res29: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] with scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = 
                    Map(2 -> Set(b) , 1 -> Set(c, a))

scala> mm.keys.toList.sortWith(_ < _).map(mm.andThen(_.toList))
res26: List[List[String]] = List(List(c, a), List(b))

scala> mm.keys.toList.sortWith(_ < _).map(x => mm.apply(x).toList)
res27: List[List[String]] = List(List(c, a), List(b))
```

Note - code from [DSLs in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/)

Is `andThen` powerful? Based on this example, it looks like `mm.andThen` de-sugars to `x => mm.apply(x)`. If there is a deeper meaning of `andThen`, then I haven’t understood it yet.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`andThen` is just function composition. Given a function `f`

```
val f: String => Int = s => s.length
```

`andThen` creates a new function which applies `f` followed by the argument function

```
val g: Int => Int = i => i * 2

val h = f.andThen(g)
```

`h(x)` is then `g(f(x))`

Comment: wheres the benefit over writing : g(f(x)) ?

Comment: @StefanKunze Maybe because it's easier to write `val h = first andThen second andThen third andThen fourth` than, for example, `val h : String => Int = x => fourth(third(second(first(x))))` :) Fun fact: F# has `>>` operator for left-to-right function composition, so you can also save a few keystrokes.

Comment: There is _no_ advantage to writing `f.andThen(g)(x)` over `g(f(x))`.  But there _is_ an advantage to writing `h(f andThen g)` over having to write another function `def fAndThenG(x:String) = f(g(x))` so that you can call `h(fAndThenG)`.  That is, if you want to pass the composed function as an argument, `andThen` allows you to do so quickly and anonymously.

Comment: why did you use `val` over `def` for functions `f` and `g`?

Comment: @StefanKunze It isn't syntactic sugar at all.  It's a function.  Syntactic sugar is *syntax* that is there to do something that other syntax could do.  Functions are concrete implementations, not syntax.  Scala has no syntax for function composition (just function application).

Comment: The way that I like to reason about function composition is that it's like a Unix pipe. You're just evaluating a function of a function, f(g(x)), or f.g (x), which ties very closely to how Unix processes output text to streams, then taken as the input of another process, and so on and forth.