# Why does the andThen of Future not chain the result?

Tags: scala, future

The `andThen` meaning I learned from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20292526/2210478) is a function composer.

Say that

```
f andThen g andThen h
```

will equal to

```
h(g(f(x)))
```

This implies the `h function` will receive input from `g(f(x))`

But for the `andThen` in `Future`, all the closure of the following andThen always receives the result from the original `Future`.

```
Future{
    1
}.andThen{ case Success(x) =>
    println(x) // print 1
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    x * 2
}.andThen{ case Success(x) =>
    println(x) // print 1
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    x * 2
}
```

compare to

```
val func: Function1[Int, Int] = { x: Int =>
  x
}.andThen { y =>
  println(y) // print 1
  y * 2
}.andThen { z =>
  println(z) // print 2
  z * 2
}
func(1)
```

What is the reason to make Future::andThen(s) receive all the same result from original Future instead of chaining Future? I've observed that these chained andThen will be executed sequentially, so the reason may not be for parallel purpose.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`scala.concurrent.Future` is designed as compromise of two asynchronous approaches:

1. Object-oriented [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which allows binding of asynchronous handlers
2. Functional [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) which offers rich functional composition capabilities.

Reading [`Future.andThen`'s docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]):

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and
>   returns a new future with the result of this future.

So `andThen` is most likely from OOP universe. To gain similar similar result to `Function1.andThen` you could use [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@map[S](f:T=>S)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) method :

```
Future(1).map {_ * 2}.map {_ * 2}
```

`andThen` differs from `onComplete` with one little thing: resulting Future of `andThen` still returning same result, but will wait until supplied observer will return or throw something. That's why there is written in the docs:

> This method allows one to enforce that the callbacks are executed in a
>   specified order.

Also note third line from docs:

> Note that if one of the chained andThen callbacks throws an exception,
>   that exception is not propagated to the subsequent andThen callbacks.
>   Instead, the subsequent andThen callbacks are given the original value
>   of this future.

So it' completely do nothing with new `Future`'s result. Could not even spoil it with it's ownt exception. This `andThen` and `onComplete` just sequential and parallel binding of observers.

Comment: Can I say It is another version of onComplete but return "this" so that it can bind multiple "observer" callback handlers in chaining style?

Comment: @ChenOT Yes. Pretty much

Comment: @But with one difference. I'll add this to asnwer

Comment: oh oh! The chain-able andThen, different to onComplete returning Unit, implies these andThen closures will be executed sequentially

Comment: onSuccess, onFailure, onComplete, and andThen are a group of functions for binding Observer callback function which may be a side effect procedure. And another group of map, flatMap, fallbackTo, recover, ... are a future composer to chain up and propagate the future result to the tail. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79798/discussion-between-chen-ot-and-odomontois).

Answer (score 2):

Let me sum up this nice discussion.

Say, we have `tf: Future[T] =...`, and two functions, `f: T => U` and `g: U => V`

We can do `vf: Future[V] = tf map f map g`, same as`vf: Future[V] = tf map (f andThen g)`

In another use case, having `fp: PartialFunction[T, U]` and `gp: PartialFunction[U, V]`,
we can run `tf1: Future[T] = tf andThen fp andThen gp` - these partial functions will be called on the value that tf produces, with no outside effect - only side effects happen. This sequence waits for `fp` before calling `gp`.

Yet another future operation, onComplete, works like this: having `f: Try[T] => U`, the call `tf onComplete f` will call `f` even if the future ended with an error; the result of `tf onComplete f` is of type `Unit`.

Also, if your function `f` produces a `Future`, you will need to use `flatMap`.

Comment: Here's something I figured out the hard way:  `tf andThen f` where `f: T => U` returns a `Future[T]` (i.e. the value of `tf`) -- not a `Future[U]` or anything else related to `f`.  I.e. the result of the full expression does not involve a composition with `f`, even if `andThen` might suggest that it does.  You might say "that's what map/flatMap is for" and you'd be right but that doesn't mean that `andThen` isn't also misleading.  Ideally `Future.andThen` would be renamed `Future.withSideEffect` or something.