# synchronized write to a file

Tags: scala, concurrency, synchronization

I knows to make sync when writing to a file easily, but the problem is when there are multiple files, we to make sync on per file. I have write some code like this to make people easily to understand what i have said

```
import java.io._
import java.util.concurrent.{ConcurrentHashMap, ConcurrentMap}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main {

  val lock: ConcurrentMap[String, Boolean] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Boolean]()

  def writeToFile(path: String): Unit = {
    while (lock.get(path)) {}
    lock.put(path, true)
    println("write to file " + path)
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    lock.remove(path)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Future {
      writeToFile("1")
    }
    Future {
      writeToFile("1")
    }
    Future {
      writeToFile("1")
    }
    while (true) {}
  }
}
```

The result will be:

```
write to file 1 [sleep 2 seconds]
write to file 1
write to file 1
```

The last two lines print at the same time. There are any another solution, please tell me :) thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your operations are not locked appropriately or atomic. While one thread may just have removed the lock from your map, two others may exit their respective while-loops simultaneously.

Also, empty infinite while loops put an unnecessary strain on your resources.

I replaced your lock map with a map that holds a `Future` for each path. The map is solely updated by its atomic `compute` method. If the path was never written before we get `null` and create our first write future. If on the other hand the path was written to before, we can just chain our new write operation. I have done this with `.map` which allows for error handling, if needed.

See [SO: future chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659427/why-does-the-andthen-of-future-not-chain-the-result) for more info on `.map` vs `.andThen`

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ConcurrentHashMap, ConcurrentMap}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object concurrent {

  val writeOperations: ConcurrentMap[String, Future[_]] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Future[_]]()

  def writeToFile(path: String): Unit = {
    val writeOp = writeOperations.compute(path, (path, future) => {
      if (future == null) {
        Future {
          println("write to file " + path)
          Thread.sleep(2000)
        }
      } else {
        future.map(x => { // you can use x for error handling of previous write operation
          println("write to file " + path)
          Thread.sleep(2000)
        })
      }
    })
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val futures = Seq(
      Future {
        writeToFile("1")
      }, Future {
        writeToFile("1")
      }, Future {
        writeToFile("1")
      }
    )

    futures.foreach(Await.ready(_, Duration.Inf))
    writeOperations.values().forEach( x => Await.ready(x, Duration.Inf))
  }
}
```